# Error when get data when using regex in php

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
<?php
$adr = 'http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-gb/';
$c = file_get_contents($adr);
if ($c){ 
    $regexp = '#<td>(.*?):(\d{1,4})</td>#';
    $matches = array(); 
    preg_match_all($regexp,$c,$matches); 
    print_r($matches);
    if (count($matches) > 0){ 
       foreach($matches[0] as $k => $m){ 
          $port = intval($matches[2][$k]); 
          $ip = trim($matches[1][$k]); 
       } 
    } 
}
```

I using `$regex = '#<td>(.*?):(\d{1,4})</td>#';` to get data inculde ip and port, but result is null, how to fix it !

Comment: Have you checked the html source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only see it properly in the browser, but in the source it's actually scrambled; you need something like this to decode it:

```
function decode($str)
{
    return long2ip(strtr($str, array(
        'fgh' => 2,
        'iop' => 1,
        'ray' => 0,
    )));
}
```

Then use it together with a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) solution like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-gb/'));

$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xp->query('//table[@id="tbl_proxy_list"]//tr') as $row) {
    $ip = $xp->query('./td/span[@class="row_proxy_ip"]/script', $row);
    $port = $xp->query('./td/span[@class="row_proxy_port"]/a', $row);

    if ($ip->length && $port->length) {
        if (preg_match('/decode\("([^"]+)"\)/', $ip->item(0)->textContent, $matches)) {
            echo decode($matches[1]) . ':' . $port->item(0)->textContent, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, just `long2ip()`, shame on me :-(

Answer (score 0):

The html source code contains ip adresses and ports separated in two columns, so that's why your regex doens't worK.